# Why does this event send me back to the starting point of my app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, meteor-helper

I am creating a Meteor app that provides a wizard-like experience, moving from one template to the next with each press of the "Next" button. For the most part, it's working as designed.

On one page, however, where I hide several "columns" of an HtmlTable until the user selects the "Add another Date" button, attempting to "add" (unhide) a column by selecting that button sends me back to "page 1" (the first template). This is the event that causes the page/template to disappear and returns the app to the first template:

```
Template.postTravelWizard.events({
    'click #addDate': function(event){
       var nextD8 = Session.get('nextDate');
       nextD8 = ++nextD8;
       Session.set('nextDate', nextD8);

       if (nextD8 == 2) {
         $("#date2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#airfare2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#pcm2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#reimbursemlg2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#rcei2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#ot2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#parktolls2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#confreg2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#lodging2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#mealsandI2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#foreignanddomestic2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#miscandenter2").removeClass("hide");
         $("#totals2").removeClass("hide");
       }
    }
}); // Template.postTravelWizard.events
```

Why would it do that?

For full disclosure, here is the pertinent HTML and JavaScript, and the pertinent CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   {{> postTravelWizard}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="postTravelWizard">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getStepTemplate}}
    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="button">
</template>

. . .

<template name="tblExpenseDescription">
  <button type="button" name="addDate" id="addDate">Add another Date</button>
  <table class="maintable" name="tblExpDesc" id="tblExpDesc" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="centertextnowrap"><strong>Description of Expense</strong></td>
        <td class="centertext"><label>Date 1: </label><input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
. . .
```

JavaScript (all of it):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // stepNum starts at 1
   Session.setDefault('stepNum', 1);
   Session.setDefault('nextDate', 1);

   Template.postTravelWizard.helpers({
        getStepTemplate: function () {
            var step = Session.get('stepNum');
            switch (step) {
                case 4:
                  return 'tblExpenseDescription'
                  break;
                case 3:
                    return 'tblPayments'
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return 'tblTravelerInfo2';
                    break;
                default:
                    return 'tblTravelerInfo'
                    break;
            }
        }
    }); // Template.postTravelWizard.helpers

    Template.postTravelWizard.events({
        'click [type=submit]': function (e, t) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //save something...
            var step = Session.get('stepNum'),
            step = (step) < 4 ? ++step : 1;
            Session.set('stepNum', step);

            if ($('#visitor').is(':checked')) {
                console.log('visitor is checked');
                var visaselection =  $('select[name="selvisatype"]').val()
                console.log('visaselection is ' + visaselection);
                // When this is working (the first two return "visaselection is undefined" and the last one returns simply
                // "visaselection is "), do something similar for ucemployee (input type=radio) and selectcampus (select element)
            }
        },
        'change .payments' : function(event){
          var paymentTot = $('#paymenttotal').val();
          paymentTot = parseInt(paymentTot) || 0;
          var targetVal = $(event.target).val();
          targetVal = parseInt(targetVal);
          paymentTot = paymentTot + targetVal;
          $('#paymenttotal').val(paymentTot);
        },
        'click #addDate': function(event){
           var nextD8 = Session.get('nextDate');
           nextD8 = ++nextD8;
           Session.set('nextDate', nextD8);

           if (nextD8 == 2) {
             $("#date2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#airfare2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#pcm2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#reimbursemlg2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#rcei2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#ot2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#parktolls2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#confreg2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#lodging2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#mealsandI2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#foreignanddomestic2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#miscandenter2").removeClass("hide");
             $("#totals2").removeClass("hide");
           }
        }
    }); // Template.postTravelWizard.events
} // if (Meteor.isClient)

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

### UPDATE

Stepping through my code when nextD8 == 2, it seems to remove the "hide" class where it should, but after stepping through my code, it goes to here:

```
return Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc(tmplInstanceFunc, function ()        
{
  return v.apply(data, args);
});
```

...and then here:

```
Template._currentTemplateInstanceFunc = oldTmplInstanceFunc;
```

(not my code, but rather template.js)

### UPDATE

For some reason, if I change the input of type submit to a button, the wrap-around from the last template to the first no longer happens when I select "Add Another Date" on the last template (good!).

However, it still does not make visible the "column". Do I need to call "invalidate" or some such to refresh the page?

Comment: Would an event.preventDefault() on the 'click #addDate' function do the trick?

Comment: No, I tried that. Theoretically, that would only be needed on a "Submit" type of button, which this is not; in this case, theory and practice coincide.

Comment: Not sure what's causing this. If you try a Session.get("stepNum") in the console, is it what you expect?

Comment: Hovering over the value shows what I expect, yes: "2" and then I can step through all my "hide this" and "hide that" lines, and then at the end it flies off into cyberspace and lands me back in Kansas (or Santa Cruz, actually).

Comment: Not 'nextDate' but rather 'stepNum'? If that were to change, your template would. Maybe an e.stopPropagation(), depending on how your buttons are placed, would fix this. But I am only guessing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, on your earlier question I was thinking of the value of "nextD8", not "stepNum"...I'll check that, too.

Comment: Did you happen to find your problem?

Comment: Not yet; noch nicht; I haven't tested stopPropogation yet, in case that button is also being fired for some reason (I'll put a breakpoint in there to check it first);

Comment: I tried event.stopPropagation(), but it makes no difference.

Comment: As a last guess I recommend `return false` at the end of the event handler. Other than that, I'm stumped.